# Dompdf, Table will not render properly for long content

Tags: php, dompdf

I would like to ask how to render the table properly, I tried to render a table but if ever the content is long, It will deform like below, it will overlap the margin of the page.

[image]

and below is the HTML source which has a bunch of table in it and sub tables inside a table cell, rendering to the browser is fine but when I try to download it in pdf using Dompdf, the table will not render properly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Documentation Proceedings</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Arial';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Arial';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
        }


        body {
            font-family: 'Arial';
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .header {
            font-size: 15px;
        }


        .table,
        .table td,
        .table th {
            border: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .table th,
        .table td {
            padding: 5px;
        }



        .policy-content .items {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }


        ol {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;
            counter-reset: item;
            text-align: justify;

        }

        li {
            display: block
        }

        li:before {
            content: counters(item, ".") " ";
            counter-increment: item
        }


        /* width */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }

        /* Track */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background: #bdbdbd;
        }

        /* Handle */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: rgb(95, 95, 95);
        }

        /* Handle on hover */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: #464d52;
        }

        .clearfix::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }

        #watermark {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            color: #d12f2fc4;
            font-size: 13px;
            /** Your watermark should be behind every content**/
            z-index: -1000;
        }

        /*Imported from the source of document_content.css*/
        table.ordered-list tr td.ol-label,
        table.ordered-list tr td.ol-content {
            vertical-align: top;
            text-align: left;
            border: 0px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <th>
                    <center>
                        <img style="width:110px;" src="http://cdn.sportscity.com.ph/images/sci_logo_2.png"><br>
                        <span class="header">
                            PHILIPPINES
                        </span>
                    </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <center>
                        <span class="header">
                            Human and Resource
                        </span>
                    </center>
                </th>
                <th colspan="4">
                    <center>
                        <span class="header">
                            Policy
                        </span>
                    </center>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Document Title</th>
                <td>Documentation Proceedings</td>
                <th colspan="3">Document No.</th>
                <td>HRAT-PO-001</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Effectivity Date</th>
                <td>
                    <span>
                        January 01, 2019
                    </span>
                </td>
                <th colspan="3">Revision Number</th>
                <td>002</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prepared By</th>
                <td>

                    Kevin Loquencio
                </td>
                <th colspan="3">Revision Date</th>
                <td>April 29, 2019</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <span>Reviewed By</span>
                </th>
                <td colspan="5">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>
                    <span>Approver<small>(s)</small></span>
                </th>
                <td colspan="5">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h3>REVISION LOGS</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Revision Level</th>
                <th>Effectivity Date</th>
                <th>Description of Change</th>
                <th>Change Initiator</th>
                <th>Reviewer(s)</th>
                <th>Approver(s)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>001</td>
                <td>

                    <span>
                        January 01, 2019
                    </span>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="ordered-list">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ol-label" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>1.</strong></td>
                                <td class="ol-content" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>OBJECTS:</strong>
                                    <table class="ordered-list">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="ol-label"><strong>1.1.</strong></td>
                                                <td class="ol-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                                                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                                                    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                                                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                                                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                                                    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                                    Ipsum.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="ol-label"><strong>1.2.</strong></td>
                                                <td class="ol-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                                                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                                                    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                                                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                                                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                                                    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                                    Ipsum.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="ol-label"><strong>1.3.</strong></td>
                                                <td class="ol-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                                                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                                                    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                                                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                                                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                                                    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                                    Ipsum.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="ol-label"><strong>1.4.</strong></td>
                                                <td class="ol-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                                                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                                                    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                                                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                                                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                                                    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                                    Ipsum.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="ol-label"><strong>1.5.</strong></td>
                                                <td class="ol-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                                                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                                                    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                                                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                                                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                                                    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                                    Ipsum.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="ol-label"><strong>1.6.</strong></td>
                                                <td class="ol-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                                    and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                                                    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                                                    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                                                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                                                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                                                    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                                    Ipsum.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ol-label" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>2.</strong></td>
                                <td class="ol-content" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>SCOPE:</strong><br>Lorem
                                    Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                                    been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                                    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                                    remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                                    Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ol-label" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>3.</strong></td>
                                <td class="ol-content" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>TABLE HEADS:</strong>
                                    <table class="ordered-list">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="ol-label"><strong>3.1.</strong></td>
                                                <td class="ol-content">
                                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th>asd</th>
                                                                <th>asdas</th>
                                                                <th>asdas</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>asda</td>
                                                                <td>asd</td>
                                                                <td>d</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>sd</td>
                                                                <td>asdsa</td>
                                                                <td>d</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                                                                    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                                                                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                                                                    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                                                                    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                                                                    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                                                                    into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                                                                    unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                                                                    release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
                                                                    passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
                                                                    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                                                                    Lorem Ipsum.</td>
                                                                <td>dasd</td>
                                                                <td>asdas</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td>Kevin Loquencio</td>
                <td>
                    Test Reviewer<br>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Test Approver<br>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>002</td>
                <td>
                    <span>
                        January 01, 2019
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="ordered-list">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ol-label" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong></strong></td>
                                <td class="ol-content" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>test:</strong><br>Lorem
                                    Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
                                    been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                                    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                                    remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                                    Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>Kevin Loquencio</td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>
    <table class="ordered-list">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="ol-label" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>1.</strong></td>
                <td class="ol-content" style="padding-bottom: 1em;"><strong>SCOPE:</strong><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply
                    dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
                    dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
                    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                    release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
        # instantiate and use the dompdf class
        $dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
        $dompdf->loadHtml($template);
        $options = new \Dompdf\Options();
        $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
        $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
        $dompdf->setOptions($options);
        # (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
        $dompdf->setPaper('letter', 'portrait');
        # Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();
        # Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $dompdf->stream($filename, array("Attachment" => true));
```

Comment: Where's the code to reproduce that error?

Comment: i updated the post above

Comment: Still, where's the code for that "download it in pdf"-feature?

Comment: done update with the post above

Comment: Did you already found the answer?